# What is the relationship between the HPA and ReplicaSet in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I can't seem to find an answer to this but what is the relationship between an HPA and ReplicaSet? From what I know we define a Deployment object which defines replicas which creates the RS and the RS is responsible for supervising our pods and scale up and down.

Where does the HPA fit into this picture? Does it wrap over the Deployment object? I'm a bit confused as you define the number of replicas in the manifest for the Deployment object.

Thank you!

Comment: "adjusts the number of replicas in a replication controller or deployment" https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When we create a deployment it create a replica set and number of pods (that we gave in `replicas`). Deployment control the RS, and RS controls pods. Now, HPA is another abstraction which give the instructions to deployment and through RS make sure the pods fullfil the respective scaling.

As far the k8s doc: The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on some other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can't be scaled, for example, DaemonSets.

A brief high level overview is: Basically it's all about controller. Every k8s object has a controller, when a deployment object is created then respective controller creates the rs and associated pods, rs controls the pods, deployment controls rs. On the other hand, when hpa controllers sees that at any moment number of pods gets higher/lower than expected then it talks to deployment.

Read more from k8s [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)

Comment: Thank you! So is it correct to say that an HPA talks to the Deployment object to reset the `replicas` key to a new minimum? Also, is it a 1:1 mapping between a Deployment and a pod?

Comment: Basically it's all about controller. Every k8s object has a controller, when a deployment object is created then respective controller creates the rs and associated pods, rs controls the pods, deployment controls rs. On the other hand, when hpa controllers sees that at any moment number of pods gets higher/lower than expected then it talks to deployment.

Comment: Great, thank you! I'll accept the answer when I can :]

Comment: @SahadatHossain, should we mention both in Deployment manifest(yml), or one at a time? Say have set the replicas=2 in deployment and HPA is set to min 5 and max 10. In that case, which has the more authority. I would have thought usually it should be one not both together. Am I correct?

Comment: if you have HPA set to min 5 and max 10, and you give replicas=2 in the yaml manifests then first it will create 2 replicas then when it will see that you have HPA min is 5 it will scale and bring 3 more replicas to make it at least 5. First your manifests will be applied then HPA will be respected.

Comment: @SahadatHossain, I understand it, but just asking, is there any point in declaring both? You could achieve the desired result just by setting min value in HBA, isn't it?

Comment: "If you plan to use HPA with a Deployment or a StatefulSet, do NOT declare replicas. If you do, each rolling update will cancel the effect of the HPA for a while. Define replicas only for the resources that are NOT used in conjunction with HPA." - https://technologyconversations.com/2018/10/10/to-replicas-or-not-to-replicas-in-kubernetes-deployments-and-statefulsets/

Answer (score 1):

Confirming what @joe-bowbeer says in comment in other answer.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#migrating-deployments-and-statefulsets-to-horizontal-autoscaling says you should remove `spec.replicas` from `Deployment` if you are using an HPA:

> When an HPA is enabled, it is recommended that the value of spec.replicas of the Deployment and / or StatefulSet be removed from their manifest(s). If this isn't done, any time a change to that object is applied, for example via kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml, this will instruct Kubernetes to scale the current number of Pods to the value of the spec.replicas key. This may not be desired and could be troublesome when an HPA is active.